# Solr : Search for synonyms of query substring

Tags: solr, synonym

We wanted to search for synonyms of query strings.
if I have "pm, project manager" entry in synonym file. I am getting results properly if I am searching for "pm" or "project manager".

But when I am searching for "**project manager** operations", Solr not giving proper results including search results of "pm". But when I debug I can see it is expanding "project manager" to "pm"

Following is my configuration

```
<fieldType name="text_jobs_synonym" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>  
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />

    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>           
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />

    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This is mm value "2<90%".

Comment: You need to specify "project manager operations", "project manager", "pm"  in your synonyms.txt file

Comment: thanks vinod for reply. We are looking for a way to identify synonyms of substring. There could be any string after project manager.

Answer (score 0):

How to Deal with Multi-Term Synonyms

Using edismax query parser to handle user queries migth help.

check this [link](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/10/27/why-is-multi-term-synonyms-so-hard-in-solr/)